# How to use feathersjs client for both websocket and restful connection?

Tags: feathersjs

I have configured both primus and restful service on my feathersjs server. Below is the configuration code.

```
app
  .use(compress())
  .options('*', cors())
  .use(cors())
  .use('/', serveStatic(app.get('public')))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(swagger({
    docsPath: '/docs',
    uiIndex: path.join(__dirname, '../public/docs.html'),
    info: {
      title: process.env.npm_package_fullName,
      description: process.env.npm_package_description
    }
  }))
  .configure(primus({
    transformer: 'websockets',
    timeout: false
  }, (primus) => {
    primus.library();
    primus.save(path.join(__dirname, '../public/dist/primus.js'));
  }))
```

On client side, below is the code to use Primus as the connection method which is websocket in this case. How can I use restful on client side in this case? The service methods defined in feathersjs are same for websocket and restful. How can I make a specific restful call instead of websocket?

```
const feathers = require('feathers-client');
const rest = require('feathers-rest/client');
const Primus = require('../public/dist/primus.js');
let primus = new Primus('http://localhost:3030');
let app = feathers()
  .configure(feathers.hooks())
  .configure(feathers.primus(primus));
```

I have read the instruction from https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/rest.html and I know how to request rest or websocket connection separately. I don't know how to combine them into one client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to. Feathers works completely through either REST **or** Websockets, there is no need to use both in the same app. Normally we recommend the Websocket connection if possible since you will also get real-time events and requests are faster once the connection is established.

What the connection configuration on the client really does is initialize a standard service that uses the connection to talk to a remote service when `app.service('anything')` is called. If absolutely necessary you can [import and instantiate one of the REST clients](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-rest/tree/master/src/client) and register it as a service on your app manually:

```
const SuperAgentClient = require('feathers-rest/lib/client/superagent');
const superagent = require('superagent');

app.use('/myservice', new SuperAgentClient({
  name: 'servicename',
  connection: superagent,
  base: 'http://my-server.com'
}));
```

Comment: Upload endpoints is not easy with sockets and is simpler with rest at the time writing. But realtime is only possible with sockets, so currently both is needed four our use case at least.

Comment: Yeah, uploading files with WS is way too complicated at this time,  uploading files as base64/binary blobs is just not always desirable especially when you plan to pass the stream next to another server instead of reading it right then and there.